# draw a rectangle with 100% opacity around the title

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

What is the most correct way, if one exists, to draw a rectangle with 100% opacity around the title of axis?

A MWE could be

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title=put me in a rectangle,
        xlabel=Cost,
        ylabel=Error]
    \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,-2.8559703)
        (3,-3.5301677)
        (4,-4.3050655)
        (5,-5.1413136)
        (6,-6.0322865)
        (7,-6.9675052)
        (8,-7.9377747)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm interested in that I have to put titles inside the canvas (which contains both grids) to reduce the wasted space.

Thank you :)

Comment: Add `title style={fill=red}` or whatever you wish to have just like a node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As percusse mentioned in his comment: define title style where you define node fill color and placement of code. For example:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
     title style={fill=yellow!30,
                 below=1em},
    title style={fill=yellow!30,
                 below=1em},
    title=put me in a rectangle,
        xlabel=Cost,
        ylabel=Error]
    \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,-2.8559703)
        (3,-3.5301677)
        (4,-4.3050655)
        (5,-5.1413136)
        (6,-6.0322865)
        (7,-6.9675052)
        (8,-7.9377747)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

**Edit:**
As mentioned Enrico in his comment, the better definition of title style is

```
     title style={draw=gray, very thick, fill=white, anchor=north east, 
                  at={(rel axis cs:.95,.9)}},
```

It with `at={(rel axis cs:.95,.9)}` and `anchor=north east` exactly determine position of title box in diagram. Also determine title box design as he liked to have. Its use in above MWE instead of my (rude) suggestion gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think I need one more. What if want to draw the border of the rectangle? I tried to add `draw` in `title style` and it worked. Then tried `draw=red`. Also worked.
And if I want to draw a thicker (or thiner) border? Can you give me a help explaining me the logic I should use to search answers to this kind of questions in the documentation of pgfplots or tikz?

Comment: Self answer: `title style={at={(rel axis cs:.95,.9)},anchor=north east,fill=white,draw=gray,very thick}`

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis, your solution is more correct as mine, which is simple hack (i didn't have time to look in manual). Congratulation! I will improve my answer with your finding.